# How can i upload a blob on my FTP

Tags: php, upload, blob

I retrieve a Blob with curl :

```
$ch = curl_init("http://MYURLFORRETRIEVEANIMAGE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
$img = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

So `$img` is my BLOB.

Now, i want to upload this blob on my ftp..And i don't know exactly what i should do ??

Thanks :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP has an [FTP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) extension. Using this, you can take the file, and upload it to your FTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Is your ftp located on the same machine as your script? If yes: just write the content of $img via [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

Comment: If its the same machine and you just want to store/write the content of $img to the local file system, yes.